# RabbitMQ streaming provider for Orleans

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, orleans

Consider we have one RabbitMQ stream in Orleans and there are some messages in the queue that are being processed. If for some reason we stop the application (messages remain in the queue) and then start the application, all the messages are retrieved when the Silo starts, and since at that moment there are no subscribers for the stream, all of them are discarded.
How to prevent Orleans from getting messages from queue before consumers are subscribed? How to process remaining messages from queue after restarting of Silo?

Configuration code of Silo:

```
var siloHostBuilder = new SiloHostBuilder()
.UseLocalhostClustering()
.Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ClusterId = "dev";
    options.ServiceId = "test";
})
.Configure<EndpointOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SiloListeningEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, siloPort);
    options.GatewayListeningEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, gatewayPort);
    options.AdvertisedIPAddress = IPAddress.Loopback;
    options.SiloPort = siloPort;
    options.GatewayPort = gatewayPort;
})
.AddMemoryGrainStorage("PubSubStore")
.AddMemoryGrainStorage("Default");

siloHostBuilder = siloHostBuilder.AddRabbitMqStream(providerName, configurator =>
{
    configurator.ConfigureRabbitMq(ob =>
    {
        ob.Configure(options =>
        {
            options.Connection.HostName = "localhost";
            options.Connection.Port = 5672;
            options.Connection.VirtualHost = "/";
            options.Connection.UserName = "guest";
            options.Connection.Password = "guest";
            options.QueueNamePrefix = queueNamePrefix;
            options.UseQueuePartitioning = true;
            options.NumberOfQueues = 1;
        });
    });
});

_siloHost = siloHostBuilder.Build();
await _siloHost.StartAsync();
```

After few seconds after this code finishes the queue is cleared.

Comment: Why are your messages being discarded? We've had similar cases where we had to restart our Silos, and the messages would be processed normally after the restart. Could you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added startup code to the question. Maybe the problem is in RabbitMQ provider itself (https://github.com/KevinCathcart/Orleans.Streams.RabbitMqStreamProvider)?

Comment: same thing happened, only the restart of silo(s) would fix it, the solution was to use ImplicitStreamSubscription